# best practices to get data from multiple databases in mysql?

Tags: elasticsearch, multi-tenant, saas

we are building a saas based application with multi-tenant databases.we are storing each organization data in a separate database. we are giving an option to search organizations by name, so if i am searching with a name i have to search in all organizations databases with that name it is taking more execution time. In future if any organizations are added, the search will take more time?
so any one please suggest me the best practices for search?

thanks